# Get from a multi dimensional array In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to point/get/assign data from a multi dimensional array if you don't have the first key?
ex.

```
Array (

 [0] => Array ( [MySKU] => BB1-3500-48 [UPC] => 721343100171 ) 
[1] => Array ( [MySKU] => BC7-3501-19 [UPC] => 721343103516 )
 [2] => Array ( [MySKU] => BC7-3501-95 [UPC] => 721343103523 ) 
[3] => Array ( [MySKU] => BB1-3502-12 [UPC] => 721343114000 )
 [4] => Array ( [MySKU] => bc7-2370-03 [UPC] => 721343121602 )
)
enter code here
```

I would like to get the UPC from the MySKU field

```
$upc = $Array[$MySKU]['UPC'];
```

will not work I have no idea the numbers only the data from the 2nd Array!

although it looks like I am missing something very simple I cannot get it to work.

I got this array from looping my sql fetch array this was the results!

Comment: Why not loop over all entries in the array and check to see if they are the entry you want?

Comment: I dont get it. Are `MySKU` variable? why there's no `$` while constructing your array?

Comment: Why not find the value you're looking for when you loop through to fetch the array in the first place?

Comment: since it cam e from a db in the first place cant you just retrieve the particular UPS in the querry

Comment: I am in middle a loop and I want to get the UPC so I dnt want to start another loop to loop through the whole array witch is huge...

Comment: The reason Why I am not asking the database for the UPC is because I don't want to aske by each record the UPC from the db since it will take a lot time.. I rather want to have the entire table into an array and then ask from the array! but I got stuck with the numbered array!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the UPC from the MySKU field as they are separate elements in the array. I think you may want
`$upc = $Array[0]['UPC']` if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the UPC of a given `$MySKU`?

If so you can:

```
foreach($results as $value) {
    if($value['MySKU'] == $MySKU) {
        $UPC = $value['UPC'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Though as mentioned in the comments, if you have the value of `MySKU` why not add that to the parameters of your query?

Comment: I am in middle a loop and I want to get the UPC so I dnt want to start another loop to loop through the whole array witch is huge

Answer (score 0):

When accessing an array you should use this notation $upc = $Array[index_of_parent_array][index_of_nested_array].

For example:

```
$upc = $Array[0]["UPC"]; //should return 721343100171
$upc = $Array[1]["MySKU"]; //should return BC7-3501-19
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the number!

Answer (score 0):

"I dnt want to start another loop to loop through the whole array witch is huge " ,

how about use funciton ,

```
$upc = gen_child_array_value($Array,'BC7-3501-19','MySKU','UPC');
```

then loop in funciton

Comment: gen_child_array_value which function is this?